# How can I clear clipboard in Remote Deskop Connection using AutoIT

Tags: c#, automation, autoit-c#-wrapper

Is there any code to check unfortunate window appears on screen while automating?

#### Where automation stops working:

```cs
public static void clearclip()
{
    var check = Sikuli.CreateSession();
    var clipErr = Patterns.FromFile(@"C:\driver\..PNG");
    auto.Sleep(100);

    clipput:   
       auto.ClipPut("");
       if(check.Exists(clipErr,3))
       {
           auto.Send("{ESC}");
       }

       if (auto.ClipGet() != "")
           goto clipput;
}
```

[image]

Comment: not sure, if it helps, but try some `sleep`. You might just have a "too fast" timing error (especially, when RemoteDesktop is involved)

Comment: Thanks for your time.  Yes I tried yet not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code you're looking for:

- Download and copy to script folder the ImageSearch library https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/
- Create a new Autoit script file and name it as you want.

  ```
  #include <ImageSearch.au3>

  While 1

      $x=0

      $y=0

      $image="example.png"

      do

         $result = _ImageSearch($image, 1, $x, $y, 0)

      until $result = 1;

      if $result=1 Then

         Send("esc")

      EndIf

  Wend
  ```

If the image is found, the variables X, Y will have width & height values

Comment: Hi thanks Adrian, It only check based on our if condition. But I am getting this image randomly .  So , is there any way that the program check by default & whenever the image is appearing it should do action with same random manner. Is that possible ?

Comment: edited the answer, please check it, I wrote from phone and I'm not 100% sure that was the correct syntax, if any trouble just comment and I will check at home